# What causes the amber/colourless/blue colours in the Briggs-Rauscher oscillating reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, color

I am using this commonly cited but simplified reaction mechanism of the Briggs-Rauscher reaction.

[image]

Reaction 1 & 2 occur simultaneously. For reaction 1, when the iodide concentration is low, the fast radical step occurs and when the iodide concentration is high, the slow non-radical step occurs.

The colourless -> amber -> dark blue oscillation of the BR reaction is due to the relative concentrations:

- I2 = amber
- I- = colourless
- I2 + I- → I3 + starch indicator = dark blue

However, I do not understand in what situations the colours arise.

- In the non-radical phase, [I-] is high but I am not sure what the
  relative concentration of [I2] is. If it is high, I'd assume there
  would be a high I3 concentration so the solution would be blue, and
  if it is low, I'd assume the [I-] would dominate so it would be colourless.
- In the radical-process, since [I-] is low, I assume the colour is amber, given by the high [I2] concentration? And because [I-] is low, there is little [I3] formed so the solution would not be blue.

During the non-radical phase, both [I-] and [I2] decreases (I think) so I'm guessing that is why the colourless stage visually appears to be much shorter than the blue or amber stage (in videos I've found online).

[MIT video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IggngxY3riU&t=72s)

Is this the right explanation for the colours?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Your explanations are correct, except that the neutral species $\ce{I3}$ does not exist. Only the anion $\ce{I3^-}$ exist.

Comment: Also I am not sure the mechanism of the radical process is correct, because it starts from the iodous acid $\ce{HIO2}$ which is not present in the initial mixture

Comment: @Maurice that is true, I'm not sure where it came from. Does the reaction start with the radical process instead of the non-radical process? I'm guessing since [I-] starts from low concentration (?), the reaction starts with the radical process?

Comment: @SoySoy4444. Both processes start from absent compounds ! The radical process starts from $\ce{HIO2}$ and the non-radical process from $\ce{I-}$, and none of these ions or molecules are present in the initial mixture. So what ??? Is it to be understood that the initial products are not really pure, containing some reduced stuff ? Just enough to start the whole series of rections ? Who knows ?

Comment: @Maurice I was wondering about that too, I found it https://people.chem.ucsb.edu/feldwinn/darby/DemoLibrary/DemoPDFs/Demo005.pdf here, do you think you could take a look? I'm guessing it's just because the reaction mechanism is simplified?

Comment: @SoySoy4444. I have read your article. It contains exactly the same mechanism, and the same equations that you wrote in the very beginning of your post. So it is no use for explaining the origin of $\ce{HIO2}$ and of the ion $\ce{I-}$.